# ASP.NET MVC Add ModelState error with a hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an item creation action where I check if item with the same name already exists in the system. I would like to add an error message with hyperlink (smth like 'An item with the same name already exists, you can open it via [url]') to ModelState. My url is not static (it is not http://google.com like in example below :)), it depends on user input.

I tried smth like

```
        ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "http://google.com");
        ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "<a href=\"http://google.com\">http://google.com</a>");
```

but everything is added as a simple text.

Can anyone help me to achieve my goal? :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can write a custom helper, i you want then i can write one for you!!

Answer (score 2):

You might try setting a ViewBag property that can be used in your view to conditionally display the link.

```
ViewBag.ErrorLink = "http://google.com";
```

Then in your view:

```
if (ViewBag.ErrorLink != null)
{
    <a href="@ViewBag.ErrorLink">@ViewBag.ErrorLink</a>
}
```